# Inverse mapping for a simple $\mathbb{R}^3$ surface given by $(\sin u, \sin 2u, v)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametric

For a domain $U=\{\, (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid -\pi<u<\pi,\ 0<v<1 \,\}$ we have a mapping $X \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$X(u,v) = (\sin u, \sin 2u, v)$.

The resulting surface is quite straightforward and looks like an infinity symbol when intersected with planes orthogonal to $z$-axis. See [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20%7Bsin%28t%29%2C%20sin%282t%29%7D).

This mapping is also injective - that is noticeable when letting $u$ gain values from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

But what is an inverse continuous map $X^{-1} \colon X(U) \to U$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sin u,\sin 2u\geq 0$ we must have $u\in[0,0.5\pi]$. If $\sin u\geq0\geq\sin2u$ we have $u\in(0.5\pi,\pi)$. Similarly,  if $\sin u,\sin 2u\leq 0$ we must have $u\in[-0.5\pi,0]$ and so on. So the inverse appears to be given as
$$
X^{-1}(x,y,z)=
\begin{cases}
(\sin^{-1}x,z)    &\text{ if }x\cdot y\geq 0\\
(\operatorname{sgn} x\cdot\pi-\sin^{-1}x,z)  &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I hope it make sense now after I finished editing it. Otherwise please ask or point out remaining mistakes!